# Python Selenium - How to call embedded javascripts?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to write a Python script to automate a process. Therefore I need interact with a webinterface. I installed Selenium and I'm able to call my webinterface and to login. Now I see a bunch of buttons but I can't just simply find them as an element as those are embedded in .js files. I can see them when I click in the browser on 'View Page source':

```
<script src="web/js/deviceWindow.js"></script>
```

When I click on deviceWindow.js I can see the Button where I want to click on:

```
this.setupButton = new Button();
this.setupButton.setText('Settings');
this.setupButton.text.addClass('configBtn');
```

How can I add this button click to my Python script?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

driver.get('http://10.143.140.220/login.html')

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('password')
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I would appreciate any help :-)
Thanks!

Comment: how about `driver.execute_script("text with JavaScript code")` ?

Comment: if buttons are displayed in window then they should be in HTML - you should check it in `DevTools`, not in source code `View Page source`. Maybe it needs to wait some time so JavaScript will have time to create these buttons in HTML. BTW: only problem can be when they are created in `Shadow DOM`

Comment: Locate the HTML of the `<button>` within the HTML and update the question.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The follwing did the job :-)

buttonclick =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[17]/div[3]/button[4]/span")
#perform click
buttonclick.click()

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, however.. is this helpful?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[...]

button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Settings')]")))
button.click()
```